# Filtering Database results in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, ruby-on-rails-3.2, filtering

I have created a rails application where users can create and apply for jobs.

As you can imagine many of these jobs come from various countries/cities and have different salaries and industries etc. I would like to create a system that will allow my users to filter through all the options to find what they're most interested in.

I would like to use a combination of radio buttons and a salary slider bar (probably Jquery) in my view to select the results that show. I would then like the page to reload (without refreshing - like AJAX) when the user hits a button called filter results.

A good example of the kind of filtering system I would like to achieve can be seen at [WIWT.com](http://www.wiwt.com) if you just click on their top filters button they have an excellent filtering system.

It would be great to know where to get started on this and whether there are any easy to use Gems already out there? Also if anyone could point me in the direction of a thorough tutorial that would be great as much of what I have found has been fairly incomplete and based around has_scope.

Thanks!

Comment: look at this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack

Comment: Looking at that railscast might be a good idea, but this can definitely be done with a form_tag, and some clever active record queries in terms of where conditions.

Comment: Thanks for both of the comments, Ransack definitely looks interesting!  @agmcleod do you have an example at all of what you're suggesting? Thanks again!

Comment: After watching the ransack episode, I highly recommend going with that. It looks to be fairly flexible. I don't have a particular example I'm afraid, but it would be more or less creating clever code that checks against what fields a user selected and put together, and building some active record logic from that.